# Port Forwarding on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure-web-roles

On a windows azure worker VM, I need to request that the azure controller forward all connections on `[public IP]:xyz` to `[worker]:xyz`. And I need to do so dynamically in C#.

I can find information about how to configure it in XML, and how to configure it using the UI, and even a few things about power shell, but nothing about how to do it in C#.

Any suggestions?